# IC product lifetime as function of junction temperature

Tags: integrated-circuit, thermal

If an IC is rated for an absolute maximum junction temperature of, say, 170°C, obviously it is not recommended to operate there - but how drastically is product lifetime impacted if we are close, say operating at a junction temperature of 160°C? How severely does an IC's lifetime get shortened as we get closer to the maximum junction temperature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two rules of thumb when it comes to premature aging of electronics and temperature:

1. Every 10°C above 25°C halves its life
2. Every 15°C above 25°C halves its life.

The 10°C is derived from a certain application of Arrhenius' equation

$$ AF = e^{ \frac{E_a}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{T_\mathrm{use}}- \frac{1}{T_\mathrm{test}}\right) $$

The issue with this is the 10°C result was a very broad interpretation of the empirical results (no consideration was given to other failure modes).

MIL-HDBK-217 took into account field data and concluded that 15°C is a figure more applicable to practical usage

https://www.electronics-cooling.com/2017/08/10c-increase-temperature-really-reduce-life-electronics-half/

Comment: I think that `Every 10°C above 25°C halves its life` is related to chemistry.

Comment: I agree, this was then broadly applied. I have been looking into this recently wrt uprating. The problem is the mail is out of date

Comment: And to just put a number to it. \$2^{\frac{160-25}{15}}=512\$. That means, if the device has a lifetime of 512 years at 25° C, then it will have a lifetime of 1 year at 160° C.

Answer (score 0):

Should be half its life with every 10°C above 125°C; with T<sub>j</sub> = 165°C, life time would be about 1 or 1.5 yr; also, plastic package may be damaged quickly.

Comment: This is a pretty old answer, but I would love to see a link to literature for this.